# How can I partially specialize a function template?

Tags: c++, templates

I can't explain myself why partial template specialization is not possible in the case below. Is there any technical reason? And mostly, is there any work around to make it work?

```
template <int a, int b>
void foo();

// DO NOT COMPILE
template <int a>
void foo<a, 999>() {
}

// COMPILE
template <>
void foo<999, 999>() {
}

template <int a, int b>
void foo() {
}
```

Comment: By *Is there any technical reason?*, do you mean to ask *Where is this specified in the standard?* or do you mean ask *Why does the standard now allow it?*

Comment: The *Where* technical reason is that clause 14.5.5 *Class template partial specializations* describes how to partially specialize a class. However there is *no* section called *Function template partial specializations* in the standard. So it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RSahu yes, basically I'm asking why the standard does not allow it

Comment: @c.bear, I don't know the answer to that. Hopefully somebody else does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use struct for partial specialization:

```
template <int a, int b> struct foo_helper { void operator()() { /*code*/ } };

template <int a> struct foo_helper<a, 999> { void operator()() { /*code*/ } };

template <> struct foo_helper<999, 999> { void operator()() { /*code*/ } };


template <int a, int b>
void foo()
{
    foo_helper<a, b>{}();
}
```

Comment: That is no 'technical' explanation

Comment: @c.bear: Any decent optimizer should inline the call. Non-optimized version would have one extra call.

Answer (score 3):

Functions can not be partially specialized. Usually it is much easier to overload a function or use SFINAE.

If it is not possible - like in this case, since SFINAE and overloads can only work on types - one can partially specialize a class having said function as it's static member - though it is usually more typing.

Comment: That is no 'technical' explanation

Comment: @DieterLücking, I am not sure what 'technical' would mean in this context.